# Android Studio import library from github where no jar file is provided

Tags: android, android-studio, shared-libraries

I want to use the API from [Maps.Me](https://github.com/mapsme/api-android). I've

- downloaded the repository from github
- extracted the files
- copied the lib folder
- created a libs folder as ...AndroidStudioProjects[MyApp]\app\libs
- pasted the lib folder into the libs folder

The instructions on github say I should then "add the library project to [my] project". My problem is that all the advice I can find here and elsewhere online assumes that I will have a jar file which I will now see in Android Studio. I don't have a jar file and I can't see a libs folder anywhere in the Project tab on Android Studio.

(The libs folder that I have created contains the folders and files that I would expect to see in an Android Studio project folder, namely res and src folders and AndroidManifest.xml, build.gradle, build.xml and project.properties files)

What do I do next?

One thought is that I should import the downloaded library as a new project into Android Studio and then create a jar file from it. Would this work? Perhaps there is an easier way?

Comment: Where they wrote "library project", think instead "library module", which is covered in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library). In particular, the docs cover [adding a library module as a dependency](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#AddDependency)

Comment: But the first step in that doc says "Add the compiled AAR (or JAR) file (the library must be already built)". Is there no way of proceeding without "compiling" a JAR first? If so, it seems odd that they would not provide a jar on github.

Comment: The first step says "Add the library to your project in **either** of the following ways" (emphasis added). The *first* of those ways is "Add the compiled AAR (or JAR) file (the library must be already built)". The *second* of those ways is "Import the library module to your project (the library source becomes part of your project)". You might try that second one. Ideally, the authors of this library would publish a JAR or AAR that you could include like many of the other libraries in your project; I do not know why they elected not to do that.

Comment: Thanks. I tried File>New>Import Module pointing at the "lib" folder (which contains res, src, AndroidManifest.xml, etc.). I accepted the default module name ":lib". Unfortunately I get a Build error "groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'propTargetSdkVersion' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension."  with no indication of what I do next.

Comment: If you look at `lib/build.gradle`, it shows references to that property, with a comment above them: "// Define these properties in the gradle.properties file in the root project folder". You would need to do that, or edit the file to no longer refer to those properties and set the `compileSdkVersion` and `buildToolsVersion` directly. Note that this library is 5+ years old, and so even if you get it imported, you may encounter issues when trying to use it.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I'm afraid this is beyond me. Apart from anything else I don't see lib or lib/build.gradle. I wonder whether a better (simpler) tack might be for me to copy and paste code from the library into my app!

Comment: "I don't see lib" -- you claimed that you did in [an earlier comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63427597/android-studio-import-library-from-github-where-no-jar-file-is-provided?noredirect=1#comment112159429_63427597). It is a directory in the project, as you can see [in the GitHub repo](https://github.com/mapsme/api-android/tree/master/lib). "or lib/build.gradle:" -- `build.gradle` is a file. Specifically, I was referring to the one in the `lib/` directory, as you can see [in the GitHub repo](https://github.com/mapsme/api-android/blob/master/lib/build.gradle).

Comment: "I wonder whether a better (simpler) tack might be for me to copy and paste code from the library into my app" -- that is certainly a possibility. Since the original has not been maintained in half a decade, you are likely to need to make changes to the code, to get it to work with modern Android app development practices. Or, perhaps you should be reconsidering using this library and the underlying service.

Comment: When you mentioned editing lib/build.gradle I assumed you were referring to something I'd find in Android Studio. I understand now that you meant the library folder that I downloaded. Anyway, I think I've taken enough of your time. Thank you very much indeed for your patience. The Android app (Maps.Me) that I'm trying to interface with is popular (over 50 million downloads and 4.5 star rating) and seems very well supported. I've had quick responses from the support team. So, I think it's worth trying to use its interface. I'll try the alternative tack of copying the library code. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone coming to this thread in future, I'll describe how I have worked around this issue.

As can be seen from the comments, I failed to import the library into my app in Android Studio, despite all the helpful guidance from CommonsWare. If I were more familiar with Android Studio, and Gradle specifically, I hope that I would have been able to succeed. However, I have followed a route which, for me with my limited experience of Android Studio, is more straightforward.

- For each class in the downloaded repository I added a new Java class to my app with the same name.
- I did not include one of the classes which included a dialog and relied on a layout and other resources, since I knew that I would not need this class
- I copied all the code, except in each case for the package name, from each class in the depository and pasted it into the new classes.
- I removed from the code that I did copy the one reference to the missing class
- the result was code that worked exactly (so far as I know) as if I had imported the library.

Obviously, the result is inelegant, but for an app that is solely for my personal use it is good enough. It works.